# How to set a custom FontWeight value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When setting font weights in Flutter I usually use preset values such as `FontWeight.normal` or `FontWeight.w500`. In my current situation I need to set a custom FontWeight. How can I set the font weight to 350 (Book)? Maybe there is a constructor I don't know about.

It would look something like this:

```
Text(
    'some text',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, //but instead of 300 it's 350
    )
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontWeight is a const parameter.
A list of all the font weights.
const [w100, w200, w300, w400, w500, w600, w700, w800, w900]

You could use FontWeight.w200 along with fontStyle:FontStyle.bold,

Just give it a try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: There's no such thing as `FontStyle.bold`.

Comment: That was an answer provide 3 years ago, there have been many updates since the answer was given.

Answer (score 3):

```
Text(
  'some text',
   style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.lerp(FontWeight.w300, FontWeight.w400, 0.5), //but instead of 300 it's 350
    )
)
```

Comment: this is ends up just outputting FontWeight.w400

Comment: Sorry, There is currently no way to implement it. There is no way to modify the font except by modifying the font itself and making it w400 to w350.